# SQL Split Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, split

I want to split every Row of a table with StartTime and StopTime to days.

Example:

```
User    Site    Title    TimeStampStart(01-11-2013)    TimeStampStop(05-11-2013)
```

I would like to obtain five Rows with day in the interval as Timestamp:

```
User    Site    Title    TimeStampStart(01-11-2013)
User    Site    Title    TimeStampStart(02-11-2013)
User    Site    Title    TimeStampStart(03-11-2013)
User    Site    Title    TimeStampStart(04-11-2013)
User    Site    Title    TimeStampStart(05-11-2013)
```

I have created a ListDates Function that allows me to split in days from two timestamps but I cannot use it as I need to use a table as argument.

Comment: Could you please detail a solution if you know how to ? Thanks

Comment: @pobrelkey are you sure about your comment?!!

Comment: Which database server are you using?

Comment: Is the data stored as dd-mm-yyyy in a varchar column, or is it actually datetime or date like it should be?

Comment: Question is not clear. Could you update the question with some real/sample data and expected results?

Comment: You should have a type column, 'Start' or 'Stop' then you can join to itself or query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a numbers table, this is fairly trivial.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Numbers(n INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT dbo.Numbers(n) SELECT TOP (1000) rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (ORDER BY [object_id]) FROM sys.all_objects;

-- if you may have dates that may be more than 1000 days apart (~3 years), 
-- increase TOP and use a cross join against one of the other system views
```

Then:

```
SELECT s.Site, DATEADD(DAY, n.n, TimeStampStart)
FROM dbo.YourTable AS s
INNER JOIN dbo.Numbers AS n
ON n.n <= DATEDIFF(DAY, s.TimeStampStart, s.TimeStampStop);
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/234ce/1)

Many examples of generating sets (and why a numbers table will typically work out best):

http://sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-1

http://sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-2

http://sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-3

Comment: Perhaps not the place to say it it, and perhaps old news, but these SQL performance articles are brilliant by the way. I continually refer to them when I see the (in my opinion) horrible practise of using recursive CTEs to generate sequences. Thanks, and thanks also for your entire bad habits to kick series.

Comment: Thanks @GarethD, appreciate the kind words.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the system table Master..spt_values to get a sequential list of integers, and join this to your source adding the integer to the start date each time (and stopping at the end date). e.g.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (TimestampStart DATETIME2, TimestampStop DATETIME2);
INSERT @T VALUES ('20131101', '20131105');

SELECT  Date = DATEADD(DAY, spt.Number, t.TimeStampStart)
FROM    @t t
        INNER JOIN master..spt_values spt
            ON spt.Number <= DATEDIFF(DAY, t.TimestampStart, t.TimestampStop)
            AND spt.Type = 'P';
```

If you are concerned that Microsoft will remove the "undocumented" table `Master..spt_values` or your dates will be more than 2047 days apart you can generate your list of numbers an alternative way:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (TimestampStart DATETIME2, TimestampStop DATETIME2);
INSERT @T VALUES ('20131101', '20131105');

WITH Numbers AS 
(   SELECT  TOP 100000 Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.Object_ID) - 1
    FROM    sys.all_objects a
            CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b
)
SELECT  Date = DATEADD(DAY, n.Number, t.TimestampStart)
FROM    @T t
        INNER JOIN Numbers n
            ON n.Number <= DATEDIFF(DAY, t.TimestampStart, t.TimestampStop);
```

Alternatively, create your own numbers table which can be used over and over again without the need to generate one on the fly each time you need one.

Comment: My personal opinion is that the table is only undocumented in the sense that there is no need to document it's purpose because it is part of the inner workings of SQL Server, rather than being there for the user's benefit thus requiring documentation. It has been there since the days of Sysbase, so I wouldn't hold your breath for it to disappear.